# Robot does not work since the Telegram has been filtered in Iran

Tags: telegram

Robot does not work since the Telegram has been filtered in Iran.

I use:

```
$url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".BOT_TOKEN."/SendMessage?chat_id=id&text=test";
file_get_contents("$url");
```

but it returns: `bool(false)`

Answer (score 0):

This block is implemented at the ISP level, so it would affect all scripts as well as Telegram itself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial to address this problem for Iranians. It uses `bypass` through `google script`:

https://www.chatted.ir/posts/telegrambot-for-iran-hosting.html